# "higher intensity" and "high signal intensity" in images

Tags: computer-vision, image-processing

I'm newbie in Computer Vision and image processing.

I'm reading the article ["Automated White Matter Hyperintensity Detection in Multiple Sclerosis Using 3D T2 FLAIR"](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4130152/) and it said:

> 2.2.4. WMH Segmentation with High Spatial Frequency Suppression
>
> White matter lesions have higher intensity and generally clear
>   boundaries relative to the surrounding WM. Unfortunately, in the 3D T2
>   FLAIR images, the GM can also present with high signal intensity,
>   especially in elderly people.

What does it means "higher intensity" and "high signal intensity"?

I think it means that white matter lesions are very white but I'm not sure because I don't understand why the use the words "intensity" and "signal" when they are talking about images.

Answer (score 1):

The intensity of a pixel is its value (e.g., from 0 to 255).  For instance, in a black-and-white/grayscale image, pixel intensity 0 means the pixel is black, and pixel intensity 255 means the pixel is white; intensities in between the two are shades of grey.

"White matter lesions have higher intensity" means that the pixels in the area of a white matter lesion have higher intensity values.

In this context "signal intensity" is presumably a synonym for "intensity".

Comment: Thanks a lot. Are there signals in images?